# Stone shape replacement in D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

I'm a big fan of of the D&D 3.5 Spell [Stone Shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/stoneshape.htm).  Is there any 4e equivalent of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not. However, it'd probably be a ritual of around 6th level. Mordenkainen's Joining (which merges two objects) is level 6; similarly, Excavation (which removes stone and earth in a tunnel) is also level 6. Stone Shape is a low to mid level spell; pegging it as a level 6 to 8 ritual allows ritual casters to learn it around the same time 3.5 casters could learn it. Adjust to suit your tastes, of course.

To fit with other level 6 rituals, the cost to learn it should be 300-350 gold pieces, and it should cost perhaps 50 gold or so to cast. If you like cheaper or free rituals it wouldn't be unbalancing to reduce the cost as much as you like.

Comment: Where can I find `Excavation`?

Comment: Dragon #366. There's an article with a bunch of random rituals in it; no particular theme.

Comment: @Bryant Stone Shape has now been introduced as a level 8 ritual, as of Dragon #405.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually make stone shape an skill challenge for nature, arcana, and dungeoneering. Complexity of the thing being created informs number of successes and difficulty.